# Bootstrap 4 navbar brand - is it possible to use a different logo at a smaller breakpoint?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have the following header logo that looks good in medium and larger sizes, but is inappropriate for smaller screens:

[image]

I can't use a responsive image, because, assuming I'm reading [the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/images/) correctly, Bootstrap simply shrinks the width while leaving the height the same.  I'm afraid the text would simply be unreadable as the width of the image is further and further constrained.

Ideally, I'd replace this logo with a smaller one at the medium break point.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps not the most elegant but quick and easy: Have two brand images, hide and show as appropriate using Bootstrap utility display classes.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/display/

Ex something like (I assume you're using .navbar-brand but the same technique works regardless):

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="logo-small.jpg" alt="Logo small" class="d-lg-none">
    <img src="logo-large.jpg" alt="Logo large" class="d-none d-lg-block">
</a>
```

This would show the small logo at sizes xs, sm & md, and large logo at lg & xl.

Comment: You don't need the `xl` declarations. `d-lg-none` (and up) is implicit. And yes, two links makes no sense as well. Just two `img` declarations

Comment: Also don't need two links afaik.

Comment: Thanks for those tips, I was apparently trying to go too fast :)